# why IIFE inside setTimeout in a for loop behaves differently in nodejs than that of browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this interesting when i executed a simple for loop with setTimeout,which is working fine in my browser,but not working in node environment.

my code is

```
function run(times) {
 for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
   setTimeout((function(j) {
     console.log(j);
   })(i), i * 10 );
 }
}

run(7);
```

while this code works perfectly fine in browser, it doesnt work in node environment. i get an error!

```
timers.js:327
throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
^

TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function
at exports.setTimeout (timers.js:327:11)
at countWithSetTimeout (E:\eckovation\temp\demo.js:3:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\eckovation\temp\demo.js:9:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: you aren't passing a function to `setTimeout`.

Comment: in the browser the code is happening so fast that it appears to be working, but in fact its doing it iteratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a function for the first argument, you're passing the *result* of an immediately invoked function. In this particular case the function has no explicit `return`, so the default return value is `undefined`, which is not a function.

Assuming you are trying to use a closure to capture the current loop iteration value, you could also just use a `let` declaration instead which is scoped to the `for` block, for example:

```
function run(times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, i * 10 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Node is correct identifying that you're *not* passing a function in `setTimeout`. The return value of the IIFE is `undefined`.

The only difference here appears to be that your browser will quietly tolerate `setTimeout(undefined, n)` while Node will not.

If you want to pass a function to `setTimeout`, you must actually `return` a `function` from your IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` requires a callback as first argument, in your code what is happening is browser ignoring this, and just executing the function inside loop and displaying it, try increasing the time(second argument of `setTimeout`), even on browser it won't have any effect, function will execute immediately.
As mentioned by other node.js correctly identifying this and throwing an error.